# error: passing 'const Tarih' as 'this' argument of 'void(int)' discards qualifiers|

Tags: c++, constants

```
void Ogrenci::ogr_dogum_tarihi_ayarla(int g,int a,int y) const
{
   dogum_tarihi.ay_ayarla(a);
   dogum_tarihi.gun_ayarla(g);
   dogum_tarihi.yil_ayarla(y);
}
```

This is my cpp file `ogrenci.cpp`

```
private:
     const Tarih dogum_tarihi;
public
     void ogr_dogum_tarihi_ayarla(int,int,int) const;
```

This is my header file `ogrenci.h`

```
void Tarih::gun_ayarla(int g)
{
    gun=g;
}
```

This is something in my cpp file `tarih.cpp`

```
private:
int gun;
```

This is something in my tarih.h

My problem is

```
ogrenci.cpp|36|error: passing 'const Tarih' as 'this' argument of 'void Tarih::ay_ayarla(int)' discards qualifiers|
```

I would like to make `dogum_tarihi` const

Can somebody help me?

Comment: You can't make it constant and call functions such as `gun_ayarla` that assign its members.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're calling a non-const method on a const object:

```
dogum_tarihi.ay_ayarla(a);
```

You can't do that. Either make the method `ay_ayarla` (and the others) const, or make the object changeable.

Comment: ay_ayarla must not be const in Tarih.cpp

Comment: @gula93 If it must not be const because it alters the object, then clearly you cannot apply it on a constant object.

Comment: Your idea makes sense .I understood that i can't use ay_ayarla for const object so should i use ">>" for dogum_tarihi_ayarla ?

Comment: @gula93 I'm sorry, but i don't see how >> is relevant in any way. I believe that if you're trying to modify an object in any way, the object should not be const. If you really insist on it, you may try to look into the `mutable` keyword.